# Перемещение данных JSON, полученных с помощью Retrofit в базу данных Room

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit, android-room

Собираюсь получить данные о курсе рубля с помощью Retrofit и добавить в базу данных Room

Есть ссылка для получение курса рубля в формате JSON
https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/latest.js

Перейдя по которой можно увидеть следующее:

```
{
    "disclaimer": "https://www.cbr-xml-daily.ru/#terms",
    "date": "2022-08-20",
    "timestamp": 1660942800,
    "base": "RUB",
    "rates": {
        "AUD": 0.0244595,
        "AZN": 0.02874918,
        "GBP": 0.0140892,
        "AMD": 6.85161458,
        "BYN": 0.0434705,
        "BGN": 0.032496758,
        "BRL": 0.08754957,
        "HUF": 6.819654,
        "HKD": 0.1324492785,
        "DKK": 0.1236012968,
        "USD": 0.016911288,
        "EUR": 0.0168368876,
        "INR": 1.34784876598,
        "KZT": 8.048743,
        "CAD": 0.02186289,
        "KGS": 1.36947655867,
        "CNY": 0.115496,
        "MDL": 0.32521277,
        "NOK": 0.1655785,
        "PLN": 0.079912,
        "RON": 0.08193,
        "XDR": 0.012841256,
        "SGD": 0.0234542,
        "TJS": 0.1734169,
        "TRY": 0.304149,
        "TMT": 0.0591894595,
        "UZS": 184.9245785,
        "UAH": 0.621129586,
        "CZK": 0.408914,
        "SEK": 0.177959,
        "CHF": 0.01619087,
        "ZAR": 0.285662,
        "KRW": 22.42268099,
        "JPY": 2.30466787
    }
}
```

Когда я, при помощи плагина `Kotlin data class File from JSON` создаю модели для получения данных о курсе рубля, создаются 2 класса:

класс `ExchangeRatesModel` (который мне не нужен, так как мне нужны только числовые значения валют)

```
data class ExchangeRatesModel(
    val base: String,
    val date: String,
    val disclaimer: String,
    val rates: Rates,
    val timestamp: Int
)
```

класс `Rates`

```
data class Rates(
    val AMD: Double,
    val AUD: Double,
    val AZN: Double,
    val BGN: Double,
    val BRL: Double,
    val BYN: Double,
    val CAD: Double,
    val CHF: Double,
    val CNY: Double,
    val CZK: Double,
    val DKK: Double,
    val EUR: Double,
    val GBP: Double,
    val HKD: Double,
    val HUF: Double,
    val INR: Double,
    val JPY: Double,
    val KGS: Double,
    val KRW: Double,
    val KZT: Double,
    val MDL: Double,
    val NOK: Double,
    val PLN: Double,
    val RON: Double,
    val SEK: Double,
    val SGD: Double,
    val TJS: Double,
    val TMT: Double,
    val TRY: Double,
    val UAH: Double,
    val USD: Double,
    val UZS: Double,
    val XDR: Double,
    val ZAR: Double
)
```

У меня есть таблица базы данных с тремя полями `id`, `name` (буду заполнять вручную), `exchange`

```
@Entity(tableName = "exchange_rate_table")
class ExchangeRateModel (

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id:Int,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "name")
    val name:String,

    @ColumnInfo(name = "exchange")
    val exchange:Double

)
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы значения всех валют были помещены в поле `exchange`

И что будет с полем id, учитывая, что в JSON значения для этого поля не передаются?

// Помещать вручную по одной переменной, мне кажется, как-то странно, но как это сделать по другому, я не знаю

Comment: Думаю лучше заменить класс `Rate` на ассоциативный массив (`Map<String, Double>`) - так вас не будет заботить изменение количества валют и вы сможете в цикле перебрать записи. Поскольку таблица небольшая, то наверное будет проще взять список записей из таблицы, просетить поля из json в объекты списка и заслать обратно прямо списком через DAO-метод с аннотацией `@Update`. И было бы проще ассоциировать котировки с именами, если в качестве `id` записи использовать тег валюты, вместо генерируемого числа

Comment: @woesss, пока что не особо понимаю, как это реализовать в коде

Comment: Элементарно. Забудьте о `Kotlin data class File from JSON`, читайте голый JSON, берите из него только обьект rates, который по сути и есть Map<String, Double> и вперед.

Comment: @semenovnikolu, в вопросе не хватает деталей, что вы используете для десериализации json в объекты? Gson? Kotlinx.serialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если используете Gson или Kotlinx.serializatoin, то вашу модель можно составить следующим образом:

```kotlin
data class ExchangeRatesModel(
    val base: String,
    val date: String,
    val disclaimer: String,
    val rates: Map<String, Double>,
    val timestamp: Int
)
```

Это позволит вам не хардкодить все возможные наименования валют, а складывать все курсы валют в `Map`. Достать нужный курс можно будет следующим образом, например, для евро:

```kotlin
val euroRate: Double? =
    exchangeRatesModel.rates["EUR"]
```

Имейте ввиду, что в таком случае не будет гарантии, что в Map находится нужная валюта. Обработайте случай, когда возвращается значение `null`.

Чтобы теперь положить все в базу, можно воспользоваться циклом:

```kotlin
exchangeRatesModel.rates.forEach { (currency: String, value: Double) ->
   // сохранение валюты currency со значением value
}
```

Comment: @semenovnikolu, этот вариант не сработал?